# How to pass QString as shared_ptr<QString> to C++?

Tags: qt, qml, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have QML code which calls C++ slot which is defined like this:-

```cpp
typedef std::shared_ptr<QString> QSString  ;

...
    //inside class declaration header
pulic slots:

    //this gives error at runtime
    void login(QSString host, QSString uname, QSString passwd) noexcept;

    // this works
    // void login(QString host, QString uname, QString passwd) noexcept;
...
```

I can call 2nd commented out function from qml side with QString just fine.

But I have some complex needs. I want to implement this slot in rust with cxx crate which.
On rust's side `QString` is opaque type and thus [must be passed through C++'s smart pointer](https://cxx.rs/extern-c++.html#opaque-c-types).

If I just run this code I get following error

```
"Could not convert argument 0 at"
         "expression for onClicked@qrc:/Login.qml:112"
qrc:/Login.qml:112: TypeError: Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is not allowed.
```

Comment: The commented function is the same as above. I guess that typo and should be `QString` instead. if yes, just add a helper function that wraps `QString` into shared pointer.

Comment: Is QSString a registered type that QML understands? A minimal, reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: Have you included "memory" in the header where login is defined?